# Nodejs-why this error while installing nodemon

Tags: node.js, package, node-modules, nodemon

`$ npm install -g nodemon`

> Error: npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ETIMEDOUT: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/is-glob failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.26.35:443
> npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.

Comment: it seem to be error with network..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).